# Need To Return GroupBy Data With Counts But Selecting Multiple Fields Using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

Okay, I'm sure this is simple for someone but it is starting to cause me to tear my hear out so I apologise in advance if this seems like a simple question:

I have the following class:

```
Public Class Ticket
    Public Property ticket_id As String
    Public Property ticket_assignee As String
    Public Property ticket_email As String
End Class
```

I am trying to use LINQ to group my list by the `ticket_email` field but allow me to get the `ticket_assignee` field and count of each group.

So for example:

For each email address, return me the assignee name and how many tickets in that email group like below:

```
'fred@someplace.com' = Fred, 4
'joe@someplace.com' = Joe, 2
'bob@someplace.com' = Bob, 8
```

etc...

I am still trying to get my head around LINQ and would love to understand it more.  Any help would be appreciated thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Query Syntax Solution:

```
Sub Main
    Dim q = from entry in Ticket.GetTickets
            group entry by entry.ticket_assignee Into NewGroup = Group, Count()
            select new with{
            .Assignee = NewGroup.Select(function(x) x.ticket_assignee).First,
            .Email = NewGroup.Select(function(x) x.ticket_email).First,
            .Count = Count}
    'q.dump()
End Sub
' Define other methods and classes here
Public Class Ticket
    Public Property ticket_id As Integer
    Public Property ticket_assignee As String
    Public Property ticket_email As String

    Public Shared Function GetTickets as list(of Ticket)

    Return New List(of Ticket) From {New Ticket With {.ticket_id = 1, .ticket_assignee = "Fred", .ticket_email = "fred@ticket.de"},
    New Ticket With {.ticket_id = 2, .ticket_assignee = "Fred", .ticket_email = "fred@ticket.de"},
    New Ticket With {.ticket_id = 3, .ticket_assignee = "Fred", .ticket_email = "fred@ticket.de"},
    New Ticket With {.ticket_id = 4, .ticket_assignee = "Anna", .ticket_email = "Anna@ticket.de"},
    New Ticket With {.ticket_id = 5, .ticket_assignee = "Anna", .ticket_email = "Anna@ticket.de"},
    New Ticket With {.ticket_id = 6, .ticket_assignee = "Jack", .ticket_email = "Jack@ticket.de"}}
    End Function
End Class
```

Gives you:

[image: LinqPad Output]

For learning Linq I highly recommend [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). You can choose VB.NET Program, copy my code, uncomment the .dump() line and run it.

Comment: Thankyou for your comments.  I had endlessly googled trying to find a solution (which I thought worked) until I tested again and found bizarre results.  However, your answer seems to work perfectly!  Thankyou.  As for LinqPad, I had attempted to use that but I struggled trying to connect it to a database and work with custom variable.  May need to study up more on that.  Thanks again.

Comment: Will this give 0 counts as well?

Comment: Nevermind....stupid question that doesn't relate to your answer sorry.  It's pretty obvious looking at the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Dim tickets As New List(Of Ticket)
            For i = 1 To 3
                tickets.Add(New Ticket With {.ticket_id = i.ToString, .ticket_email = "a", .ticket_assignee = "me"})
            Next
            For i = 4 To 6
                tickets.Add(New Ticket With {.ticket_id = i.ToString, .ticket_email = "b", .ticket_assignee = "me2"})
            Next

            Dim group = tickets.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ticket_assignee).Select(Function(y) New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(y.First.ticket_assignee, y.Count))
```